# appending to rails field value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to find and update a number of records in a Rails 3.2, Ruby 2 application. The following code successfully finds the records I want. What I need to do though is add " x" (including the space) to the email address of every user and I can't figure out how to do it.

This finds the records

```
User.joins(:account)
  .where("users.account_id NOT IN (?)", [1955, 3083, 3869])
  .where("accounts.partner_id IN (?)", [23,50])
  .where("users.staff = '0'")
  .where("users.admin = '0'")
  .where("users.api_user = '0'")
  .where("users.partner_id is null")
  .update_all(email: :email.to_s << " X")
```

but it's the last line I'm having problems with. Is this possible, or do I need to find the records another way?

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the last line like so:

```
.update_all("email = email || ' X'")
```

This uses SQL's string concatenation operator to append the `X` to the end of the emails.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Careful, this assumes that `email` is not null. In a sane world the column would be NOT NULL but stating the assumption might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The `update_all` method updates a collection of records, but unless you write your own SQL expression, it can only set one value. For example, if you wanted to overwrite all the email addresses with "X", you could do it easily:

```
User.joins(:account)
  .where("users.account_id NOT IN (?)", [1955, 3083, 3869])
  # ...other scopes...
  .update_all(email: "X")
```

In your case, what you really need to do is make individual updates to all these records. One way to do it is to find the records, then loop over them and update them one at a time:

```
users_to_update = User.joins(:account)
                      .where("users.account_id NOT IN (?)", [1955, 3083, 3869])
                      .where("accounts.partner_id IN (?)", [23,50])
                      .where("users.staff = '0'")
                      .where("users.admin = '0'")
                      .where("users.api_user = '0'")
                      .where("users.partner_id is null")

users_to_update.each do |user|
  user.update_attribute(:email, "#{user.email} X")
end
```

Another solution would be to use a SQL expression with `update_all`, as in Zoran's answer.